# Showing that, in Pascal's triangle, the product of the numbers along each median is always the same.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, intuition, factorial, products

On Pascal's triangle with any number of rows, draw the three [medians](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleMedian.html#:%7E:text=A%20median%20of%20a%20triangle%20is%20the%20Cevian,in%20the%20ratio%202%3A1%20%28Casey%201888%2C%20p.%203%29.).

[image]

For each median, calculate the product of the numbers that zig-zag along that median.

*The three products are always equal!* (proof below)

Note that, on the vertical median, every other number is either just to the left, or just to the right of the median; it makes no difference. On the oblique medians, every other number is just *below* the median (this rule applies when the number of rows is even or odd).

Here is an example with a triangle with $10$ rows (the top $1$ is row $0$):

[image]

$1\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 6\cdot 10\cdot 20\cdot 35\cdot 70\cdot 126\cdot 252=560105280000$

[image]

$1\cdot 6\cdot 15\cdot 35\cdot 35\cdot 56\cdot 28\cdot 36\cdot 9\cdot 10\cdot 1=560105280000$

This is such a simple result, so I wonder if there is an intuitive explanation. My question is:

> Is there an intuitive explanation for this result?

To give an idea of what I mean by "intuitive explanation", here are some examples:

- The sum of the numbers in the $n$th row is $2^n$, because $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}=(1+1)^n=2^n$.
- $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k ^2 = \binom {2n} n$ has an [intuitive combinatorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2232712/398708) proof.
- In the left-justified Pascal's triangle, any square matrix that shares a border with the left edge of the triangle has determinant $1$; this has an [intuitive proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4816736/398708).

### My non-intuitive proof

I prove the case when the number of rows is even, $2n$. The proof with an odd number of rows is very similar.

$P_v=$ product along vertical median $=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{2k-1}{k-1}\binom{2k}{k}$

$P_o=$ product along oblique median $=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{n+k}{2k-1}\binom{n+k}{2k}$

$\begin{align}
\dfrac{P_v}{P_o}&=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2k-1)!^2 (2k)!^2 (n+1-k)!(n-k)!}{(k-1)!k!^3 (n+k)!^2}\\
&=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{(2k-1)!^2(2k)!^2}{k!^2 (n+k)!^2}\\
&=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{(2k)!^4}{k!^2 (n+k)!^2 (2k)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(2!4!6!\dots (2n)!)^4}{(1!2!3!\dots n!)^2((n+1)!(n+2)!(n+3)!\dots (2n)!)^2(2\cdot 4\cdot 6\dots (2n))^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(2!4!6!\dots (2n)!)^2}{(1!3!5!\dots (2n-1)!)^2 (2\cdot 4\cdot 6\dots(2n))^2}\\
&=1
\end{align}$

### Context

I have been playing with Pascal's triangle, investigating some of its [mysterious](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4811425/398708), [geometrical](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4815410/398708) and [humourous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4813505/398708) properties.

Comment: Don't know if it might help, but it seems that the equality can be divided in two: $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{2k}{k}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{n+k}{2k-1}$ and $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{2k-1}{k-1}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{n+k}{2k}$

Comment: Related conjecture: Let "strict-median" numbers be along lines that don't wiggle. Then, for a $2n$ triangle, $$\frac{\text{vertical strict-median product}}{\text{oblique strict-median product}}=2^{n}$$ For instance, with your $n=5$ example,
$$\frac{1\cdot2\cdot6\cdot20\cdot70\cdot252}{1\cdot15\cdot35\cdot28\cdot9\cdot1}=2^5$$ And, note: the oblique off-median numbers (eg, your blue $6,35,56,35,10$), along with a "$1$", are the strict-median numbers for a $2n+1$ triangle. (Verticals are slightly weirder to describe.)

Comment: The algebraic form of @Blue conjecture is $\frac{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{2k}{k}}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{n+k}{2k}}=\frac{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{n+k}{2k-1}}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{2k-1}{k-1}}=2^n$.

Comment: Proof of Blue's conjecture: $\dfrac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}}{\prod\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{2k}}=\prod\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(2k)!^2(n-k)!}{k!^2(n+k)!}=\prod\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(2k)!^2}{k!(n+k)!}=\dfrac{(2!4!6!\dots (2n)!)^2}{(1!2!3!\dots n!)(n!(n+1)!(n+2)!\dots (2n)!)}=\dfrac{2!4!6!\dots (2n)!}{1!3!5!\dots (2n-1)!n!}=\dfrac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \dots (2n)}{n!}=2^n$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self-answering. I found what I consider to be an intuitive proof.

It looks long, but after you understand what it's saying, it's fairly intuitive. In fact, I thought of this proof while riding my bicycle, without writing anything.

---

Define:
$P_o(a)=$ product along oblique median in a triangle with $a$ rows.
$P_v(a)=$ product along vertical median in a triangle with $a$ rows.

The result in the OP is equivalent to $\dfrac{P_o(a+1)}{P_o(a)}=\dfrac{P_v(a+1)}{P_v(a)}$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

---

In the diagram,
$P_o(10)$ is the product of the numbers in blue and green.
$P_o(11)$ is the product of the numbers in yellow and green.

[image]

$\begin{align}
\dfrac{P_o(11)}{P_o(10)}&=\dfrac{\binom{6}{0}}{\binom{5}{0}}\cdot\dfrac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}}\cdot\dfrac{\binom{8}{4}}{\binom{7}{4}}\cdot\dfrac{\binom{9}{6}}{\binom{8}{6}}\cdot\dfrac{\binom{10}{8}}{\binom{9}{8}}\cdot\dfrac{\binom{11}{10}}{\binom{10}{10}}\\
&=\dfrac{6}{6}\cdot\dfrac{7}{5}\cdot\dfrac{8}{4}\cdot\dfrac{9}{3}\cdot\dfrac{10}{2}\cdot\dfrac{11}{1}\text{ because }\dfrac{\binom{p}{r}}{\binom{p-1}{r}}=\dfrac{p}{p-r}\\
&=\binom{11}{5}\\
&=\dfrac{P_v(11)}{P_v(10)}\\
\end{align}$

---

Or in general,
$\begin{align}
\dfrac{P_o(2n+1)}{P_o(2n)}&=\prod\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{\binom{n+1+k}{2k}}{\binom{n+k}{2k}}\\
&=\prod\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{n+1+k}{n+1-k}\\
&=\binom{2n+1}{n}\\
&=\dfrac{P_v(2n+1)}{P_v(2n)}\\
\end{align}$

A similar argument shows that $\dfrac{P_o(2n)}{P_o(2n-1)}=\dfrac{P_v(2n)}{P_v(2n-1)}$.

$\therefore\dfrac{P_o(a+1)}{P_o(a)}=\dfrac{P_v(a+1)}{P_v(a)}$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$.